# validar solo letras y evitar copy paste

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

hola este código restringe que se puedan poner números en mi input que solo debe admitir texto y caracteres especiales como el espacio, pero si yo copio y pego números me los admite como puedo restringir el copy paste de números pero si permitir el de letras y espacios o caracteres??

```
function sololetras(evento){
          key = evento.keyCode || evento.which;
            teclado = String.fromCharCode(key).toLocaleLowerCase();
            letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
            especiales = "8-32-37-38-39-46-164";

            teclado_especial = false;
            for (var i in especiales) {
                if (key == especiales[i]) {
                    teclado_especial = true; break;
                }
            }
            if (letras.indexOf(teclado) == -1 && !teclado_especial) {
                return false; 
            }
          }
```

aqui llamo al evento solo letras:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ej: Ford lobo azul" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" >
```

Comment: Ya habías hecho esta pregunta, no?

Comment: Esto esta en ingles, pero te puede esclarecer tu dudas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958478/how-to-disable-copy-paste-browser Hay varias opciones, casi siempre evitando algunas combinaciones de teclado y deshabilitando el botón derecho del mouse.

Comment: si pero no e obtenido respuesta y volví a publicar , e buscado diferentes formas de hacerlo pero ninguna se ajusta a lo que necesito

Comment: gracias por la información pero a lo que entiendio en ese post tratan de bloquear la opción de copiar y pegar y yo no la quiero bloquear quiero denegar solo el pegar números en un input pero si permitir el pegado de letras

Comment: ¿Dónde llamas esta función? ¿Con que evento?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ej: Ford lobo azul"  onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" >

Comment: pongo un onkeypress en el input donde voy a denegar que coloquen numeros

Comment: revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allows-only-numeric-input...debes aplicar una expresión regular para ello donde admitas solo letras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que hay una solución mas sencilla para este caso, podrías realizar la validación en el evento `oninput` verificando si el texto contiene números en ese caso solo tendrías que eliminarlos del valor del input:

```js
const validar = function(campo) {
  let valor = campo.value;
  
  // Verifica si el valor del campo (input) contiene numeros.
  if(/\d/.test(valor)) {
  
    /* 
     * Remueve los numeros que contiene el valor y lo establece
     * en el valor del campo (input).
     */
    campo.value = valor.replace(/\d/g,'');
  }
  
};
```

```html
<input oninput="validar(this)" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono a la perfección y si era una manera mas sencilla aveces nos empeñamos en hacer las cosas de una manera cuando por lógica se puede hacer a la inversa pero estaba bloqueado intentando hacerlo de solo una manera